# Skip the CURRENT ROW and apply analytical function for all remaining rows in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Skip the **CURRENT ROW** and apply analytical function for all remaining rows in `PARTITION BY` clause in SQL Server 2012

Example: I have 12 rows of data in a table and I want to calculate and append the `AVERAGE` of entire column by skipping the `CURRENT ROW` value.

```
COL1    COL2    AVG_SKIP_CUR_ROW 
a          3    7.71
a          6    7.28
a          6    7.28
a          8    7
a          12   6.42
a          5    7.43
a          8    7
a          9    6.86
```

Comment: If you mean all rows in the frame except the current row then (and I'm guessing) `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  AND 1 PRECEDING` might get you everything up to the current row, `ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` might get the rest. You'd then have to combine the two results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following up on my comment, if you wish to apply the function to everything after the current row, use `ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` or for everything before the current row, `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`

Here's a simple example of (a possible, might not be ideal) way to combine these to exclude the current row. In this case, a simple `SUM` aggregate (you could do this in a single select, I split it into a sub query for clarity):

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(Val INT)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

SELECT Val, SumPreceding+SumFollowing SumExcludingCurrent FROM (
    SELECT Val
    ,ISNULL(SUM(Val) OVER (ORDER BY VAL ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) SumPreceding
    ,ISNULL(SUM(Val) OVER (ORDER BY VAL ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), 0) SumFollowing
    FROM #Test
    ) A
ORDER BY Val

Val         SumExcludingCurrent
----------- -------------------
1           14
2           13
3           12
4           11
5           10
```

For your update, since you're calculating the average of the col excluding the current value, this simplifies to:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(Col1 CHAR, Col2 INT)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('a',3),('a',6),('a',6),('a',8),('a',12),('a',5),('a',8),('a',9)

SELECT Col1
       ,Col2
       ,(SUM(Col2) OVER () - Col2) / CAST(COUNT(*) OVER() - 1 AS NUMERIC(4,2)) Avg_Skip_Cur_Row
    FROM #Test


Col1 Col2        Avg_Skip_Cur_Row
---- ----------- ---------------------------------------
a    3           7.714285
a    6           7.285714
a    6           7.285714
a    8           7.000000
a    12          6.428571
a    5           7.428571
a    8           7.000000
a    9           6.857142
```

And because I was having fun with this, here's another version. Since the test data doesn't have a key, I've added a row number.

```
SELECT
    Col1
    ,Col2
    ,(ISNULL(SUM(Col2) OVER (ORDER BY rn ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) +
      ISNULL(SUM(Col2) OVER (ORDER BY rn ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),0)) /
      CAST(COUNT(*) OVER() - 1 AS NUMERIC(4,2)) Avg_Skip_Cur_Row
FROM 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col2) rn FROM #Test) A
```

Comment: The _frame clause_ with two `PRECEDING` keywords also works in AWS Redshift syntax. Thanks!